# How to solve the logarithmic equation $\log_2 (1 + \sqrt{x}) = \log_3 x$ analytically

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$$\log_{2}{(1+\sqrt{x})}=\log_3x$$ I find $x=9$ solution of this equation (by graphing).  Is there a way to solve it analytically ? 
$$x=9 \to \log_{2}{(1+\sqrt{9})}=\log_39  \space \checkmark$$
Remark:this question belong to calculus 1 exam of polytechnic university of Tehran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$1 = 1 $$

$$\log_a a = \log_b b $$

$$n\log_a a = n\log_b b $$

$$\log_a a^n = \log_b b^n $$

then $ \sqrt x + 1 =2^n$ ....

$ x =(2^n -1)^2$

$ 3^n =(2^n -1)^2$

So for $n=2m $ even it gives

$ 3^m =(4^m -1)$

$m = 1$ is a solution..

Comment: @Isham:You said m=1 is a solution ..., may not be there more solution  ?

Comment: @Khosrotash oh you asked how to deduce that x=9 is a solution with some logics so I did...But it is not taht hard to show that the function $f(x)=3^x, g(x)= 4^x-1$ will never meet again...with m increasing...

Comment: yw  g is increasing faster than f  so they meet at x=1 but never again

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $1 + \sqrt x=z$  so we have $x=(z-1)^2$

The equation becomes

$\log_{2}{z}=\log_3(z-1)^2$

$\log_{2}{z}=2\log_3(z-1)$

Convert in natural log

$\dfrac{\log 3 \log z}{2 \log 2}=\log (z-1)$

$\dfrac{\log 3}{\log 4}=\dfrac{\log (z-1)}{\log z}$

$z=4$ is the unique solution of this equation since $f(z)=\dfrac{\log (z-1)}{\log z}$ is  increasing for any $z>1$.

Indeed $f'(z)=\dfrac{-z \log (z-1)+\log (z-1)+z \log z}{(z-1) z \log ^2 }$ is positive when numerator $-z \log (z-1)+\log (z-1)+z \log z>0$ that means

$z> \dfrac{\log (z-1)}{\log (z-1)-\log (z)}$ which is verified for any $z>1$ as the RHS is less than $1$

Therefore 
$z=4\to x=(z-1)^2=(4-1)^2\to x=9$

which is the only solution of the equation

Hope this helps

Comment: Raffaele.z=4 is one solution. Is it the only solution of the z - equation? The f' > 0 ,  argument , Marty and John, decides this question. Please comment.

Comment: Intuitively as $\log z$ is monotonic (strictly increasing) in $\mathbb{R}^+$ then $\dfrac{\log (z-1)}{\log z}$ has the same property. But to prove it we need derivative, I agree with you

Answer (score 3):

Let $u=1+\sqrt{x}$ so that $x=(u-1)^2.$  Then the equation is

$$\log_2 u = \log_3(u-1)^2 = 2\log_3(u-1) = y,$$

where $y$ is some number.  Then $2^y=u$ and $3^{y/2} = u-1.$  Then

$$3^{y/2} = 2^y -1 = 4^{y/2} - 1$$

or

$$4^{y/2} - 3^{y/2} = 1$$

so we conclude that $y/2 = 1$, so $y=2$, and $u=4$ and $x=9.$

Fun problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't get it. There is rather standard way to do it. Calculate the derivate of 
$$ f(x) = \log _2 (1+\sqrt{x}) - \log _3 x$$ and show that it is monotonic. Thus result (that is 9 is the only solution, which you ''guess'').

Comment: The OP wants to know if he could solve this with pencil and paper if he didn't know the solution in advance.  (Or more generally, if the solution weren't conveniently an integer.)

Answer (score 2):

$\log_{2}{(1+\sqrt{x})}=\log_3x
$
is the same as
$\dfrac{\log(1+\sqrt{x})}{\log 2}=\dfrac{\log x}{\log 3}
$.

The logs can be to any base. It doesn't matter,
as long as they are all the same.

Cross-multiplying,
$\log 3 \log(1+\sqrt{x})
=\log 2 \log x
$
or
$\log((1+\sqrt{x}))^{\log 3 }
= \log (x^{\log 2})
$
or
$(1+\sqrt{x}))^{\log 3 }
=x^{\log 2}
$
or
$1+\sqrt{x}
=x^{\log 2/\log 3}
$.

If
$f(x)
=x^{\log 2/\log 3}-(1+\sqrt{x})
$,
then
$f(1) = -1$
and
$f'(x)
=c x^{c-1}-\frac12 x^{-1/2}
$
where
$c = \frac{\log 2}{\log 3}
\approx .6309
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
f'(x)
&=c x^{c-1}-\frac12 x^{-1/2}\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}(2c x^{c-1/2}-1)\\
&\gt 0
\qquad\text{for } x > 1\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$f(x)$
can have at most one root
for $x > 1$.
Since $x=9$
is a root,
it is the only root.